# SIFT Keypoint Location

Tags: image-processing, sift, hessian-matrix

I am currently working in **SIFT**, I had generated the difference of Gaussian and the extrema image layers. Can anyone explain to me how to use Hessian matrix to eliminate the low contrast keypoint?

Comment: You might want to explain yourself a little better. Not many people specialize in CV. Also, the correct tagging of your question helps others find your question better.

Comment: I am currently working on image feature extration to form descriptor for my pattern matching.

Comment: The Hessian matrix is used to eliminate features along edges/lines not `low contrast keypoints`. See the [related section of the SIFT entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Eliminating_edge_responses) on Wikipedia. This is a rather simple operation.

Comment: I found this post really clear in explaining and implementation about SIFT http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform/ And maybe this one will help you: http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform/5/

Comment: The above links doesn't work. There's now: http://aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/ and http://aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-eliminate-low-contrast/

Answer (score 1):

A *good* keypoint is a corner. This comes from the Harris corner work and the *Good features to track* (KLT) papers first, then emphasized by the [Mikolajczyk and Schmid paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/search?q=A%20Performance%20Evaluation%20of%20Local%20Descriptors.).

Intuitively, a corner is a good feature because it is an intersection of two lines, while a single line segment can be moved along its direction, thus causing a less accurate localization.
A line segment is an edge, i.e., a first order derivative (gradient). A corner is an edge that changes its direction abruptly. This is measured by a second order derivative, hence the use of the Hessian matrix that contains the values of the directional second derivatives.